# Third parameter in a function is an optional object with default values. How to write it to make typescript happy?

Tags: typescript

Consider this function:

```js
const resizeImage = async function resizeImage(
  buffer: Buffer,
  name: string,
  { width = 500, height = 500, ...others }: { width?: number; height?: number }
) {
  Logger.info('hello from resizeImage');

  /**
   * ## cropping the image
   */
  await sharp(buffer)
    .resize({
      fit: sharp.fit.cover,
      width,
      height,
      ...others,
    })
    /**
     * ## convert to jpeg
     */
    .toFormat('jpeg')
    /**
     * ## set quality
     */
    .jpeg({ quality: 90 })
    /**
     * ## save to file
     */
    .toFile(`public/img/${name}`);
};
```

Now i call it from my main module

```js
await resizeImage(req.file.buffer,req.file.filename) //EXPECTED 3 ARGUMENTS, BUT GOT 2
```

I don't want to specify the third object param here, i'm ok with the defaults

I've tried a multitude of things, from making the whole third object optional to this:

```js
export interface ResizeOptions {
  width: number;
  height: number;
  [key: string]: any;
}

const resizeImage = async function resizeImage(
  buffer: Buffer,
  name: string,
  // resizeOptions: Partial<ResizeOptions>
  // resizeOptions: Record<string, any>
  // { width = 500, height = 500, ...others }: { width?: number; height?: number }
  // { width = 500, height = 500, ...others }?: { width?: number; height?: number }
  { width = 500, height = 500, ...others }: Partial<ResizeOptions>
) {
...
}
```

I also don't want to assign a default object to `resizeOptions`, as eslint warns be about mutations:

```js
const resizeImage = async function resizeImage(
  buffer: Buffer,
  name: string,
  // resizeOptions: Partial<ResizeOptions>
  // resizeOptions: Record<string, any>
  // { width = 500, height = 500, ...others }: { width?: number; height?: number }
  // { width = 500, height = 500 }: Partial<ResizeOptions>
  resizeOptions = {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
  } // Do not use an object literal as default for parameter `resizeOptions`. [unicorn/no-object-as-default-parameter
) {
...
}
/**
explanation: Default parameters should not be passed to a function through an object literal.
 The foo = {a: false} parameter works fine if only used with one option.
 As soon as additional options are added, you risk replacing the whole foo = {a: false, b: true} object when passing only one option: {a: true}.
 For this reason, object destructuring should be used instead.
*/
```

I can't get typescript to stop complaining.

How would I go implementing this?

Thank you

I've tried all the above

Comment: "I also don't want to assign a default object to resizeOptions, as eslint warns be about mutations"  Isn't that an `eslint` issue and nothing to do with TypeScript?  If you want to have an optional input and you want it to destructure then you have to assign a default object.  You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/m07kqN)... does that not meet your needs for some reason? If not, why not?  If it does meet your needs I'll write up an answer explaining.  Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: (continued) Also, if you have an answer to your own question, [you should post it as an answer and not edit it into the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267439/2887218).

Comment: @jcalz thank you, your solution is what's needed. also fixed the answer as suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MY SOLUTION: so the way i was able to implement it hacking my way through eslint was specifying a default object as to my understanding you can't have an optional object + optional object values AND avoid assigning the default optional object.

```js
export interface ResizeOptions {
  width: number;
  height: number;
  [resizeOptionName: string]: any;
}

const resizeImage = async function resizeImage(
  buffer: Buffer,
  name: string,
  // eslint-disable-next-line unicorn/no-object-as-default-parameter
  resizeOptions: ResizeOptions = {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
  }
) {
  Logger.info('hello from resizeImage');

  const { width = 500, height = 500, ...others } = resizeOptions;

  /**
   * ## cropping the image
   */
  await sharp(buffer)
    // .resize({
    //   width: 500,
    //   height: 500,
    //   fit: sharp.fit.cover,
    // })
    .resize({
      fit: sharp.fit.cover,
      width,
      height,
      ...others,
    })
    /**
     * ## convert to jpeg
     */
    .toFormat('jpeg')
    /**
     * ## set quality
     */
    .jpeg({ quality: 90 })
    /**
     * ## save to file
     */
    .toFile(`public/img/${name}`);
};
```

This way, even if you risk mutating the default values, you can't choose to specify the optional object without assigning both width and height, you must write width: 1000, height: 500 even if height wouldn't be needed as it won't alter the default value for height

@jcals solution in the comment above works too, you need to initialize an object in the function declaration if you want to keep it optional